# Joining two tables and two junction tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, junction-table

I have these tables:

- Games (game_id,game_name, etc)
- Teams (teams_id,team_name, etc)
- Players (players_id, player_name, etc.)

junction tables:

- games_teams  (game_id,teams_id)
- teams_players (teams_id, player_id)

Basically for every game I want to see the number of teams and the number of players.

Game name - Number of teams - number of player

Using inner join I managed to join games with teams but not with players. I believe it involves multiple select statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join `games` and `teams` with the help of the `games_teams` junction table. Then, you can join that with `teams_players` to get the player IDs. Note that for this query you don't even need the `players` table, since you just needs their number:

```sql
SELECT   game_name, 
         COUNT(DISTINCT gt.team_id) AS number_of_teams,
         COUNT(DISTINCT tp.player_id) AS number_of_players
FROM     games g
JOIN     games_teams gt on g.game_id = gt.game_id
JOIN     teams t ON gt.team_id = t.team_id
JOIN     teams_players tp ON t.team_id = tp.team_id
GROUP BY game_name
```

Comment: Thank youuuu!! worked but i changed to LEFT JOINS. spend 3 hours on this!